# Can't run command rails console on EC2 after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use `AWS` with `Elasticbeanstalk` to deploy my applications, but I can't run the command `rails console` once ssh to my server and going to `/var/app/current`.

I tried many commands, without success :

- `bundle exec rails c`
- `RAILS_ENV=development rails c`

I got the follow error:

```
Could not find addressable-2.3.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But when running `bundle install` everything is fine.

This error is a huge issue to me as I can't use the `whenever` cron job.

Can you help me ?

PS : Gist of my Gemfile [here](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-besnard/1e19189c9f8c5fac8e64)

Comment: Is your EC2 using a system ruby or something like RVM?

Comment: My EC2 instance is running Ruby. I'm not sure for RVM (command not found).

Comment: Have you tried `bundle exec rails c production` ?

Comment: Yes, I got `Could not find addressable-2.3.6 in any of the sources
Run bundle install to install missing gems.`

Comment: Could you add your  `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` as well as the output of `gem list addressable` ?

Comment: Here : https://gist.github.com/nicolas-besnard/1e19189c9f8c5fac8e64

Comment: The gem `launchy` is one who depends on `addressable`. Maybe you are having an issue with `bundler`. Could you try updating it with `gem update bundler` and try `bundle install` again ?

Answer (score 1):

ran into similar problem and this is what solved my problem:

you may try `sudo gem install bundler` from your root and later move to `app/current` and try run `rails c -e environment_name`

Comment: Well, my problem is fixed since I update my EB environment to the last update. However, I still need to change the CHMOD of my `log` directory to get access to `rails c`